# Is it a bad practice to use script templates in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, templates

I have learned underscoreJS and backboneJS, and in backboneJS it is possible to specify templates in HTML this way:

```
 <script type="text/template" id="id1">Template</script>
```

and then apply them with underscore.
The question is, is it valid to (or should I) do it without using backboneJS.

For example if I am using only underscoreJS and I just want an HTML template to be able to use with javascript (without backboneJS), would it be appropriate to write those templates?

And if I am not using underscoreJS, would it be not a bad practice to write those HTML template to be able to access them with jQuery (even without underscoreJS)?

Comment: underscore is simply a javascript library so using this with another library is really no different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've seen this used for templates, though I saw type="text/html".  In any case, this is a valid use for defining templates while all browsers don't support <template> yet (older IE).

And it's not bad.  It's a good thing.  Any way to remove html out of your JS is a +plus!

Comment: can use any type value that isn't script related. Angular for example uses a special one so it is recognizable to the framework

Comment: So, if I will use 1<script type="text/html" id="id1">Template</script>`, it wont be displayed on the page and I will be able to access it and to use it without underscoreJS and backboneJS without any problems? And it will be completely valid?

Comment: The script tag will be selectable by its id or whatever you give it to select by, and then you can just access it's html()

Comment: @charlietfl as I know angularJS uses its own attributes and not types. What types are you talking about exactly?

Comment: @MyOwnFan when angular templates are in script tags they use `type="text/ng-template"` ... in other words they use the same practice that you are asking about https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/script . The type can be pretty much anything other than `"javascript"`

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks a lot, that was very usefull

Comment: @MyOwnFan i wouldn't use type="text/html", the browser will parse what's in the script tag (but not display it) and create additional overhead without any added bonuses. The other downside of not using the html5 template tag is you can't include other script tags inside of a script tag. If possible, use a polyfill for html5 template tags.